# Value is coming undefined first, then is coming alright, but still receive undefined on the page render and it's show error when i show data in UI

Tags: reactjs

I managed to update a PRODUCT value from the database, but I want to get the value now in the interface, so the user will see exactly the value from the database.

[what I code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5d1x.png);

[data i found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVKW9.png)

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUkzO.png)

So if I console.log ITEM, I'm getting undefined and then data show after it said undefined here are the logs:

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Comment: you can just use Smartphones && Smartphones.map()

Answer (score 0):

U need to use async/await in your code which asynchronous operations like fetching data from a database which will give u the data once available

Comment: Here I use Async await function. but the problem is not fixed yet.  code: https://prnt.sc/5nSsYVrElsjJ , result: https://prnt.sc/XhTaE28qmVT5

Answer (score 0):

Define ***smartPhone*** as a state:

```
const [smartPhone, setSmartPhone] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
 if(popular.length > 0) setSmartPhone(popular)
},[popular])
```

And return:

```
{
   smartPhone.length > 0 && (
      smartPhone.map(
         // Your code...
      )
   )
}
```